# Can I leave out parts of a CC BY-ND licensed work when distributing it?

Tags: creative-commons, distribution, cc-by-nd

I want to redistribute a work licensed under [CC BY-ND 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/3.0/).

The license summary says about ND (NoDerivatives):

> If you **remix, transform, or build upon** the material, you may not distribute the modified material.

It says that "Merely changing the format never creates a derivative.".
But what about leaving parts (except for copyright notices) out? Does this count as "remix, transform, or build upon"?

#### Example

1. A book released under CC BY-ND 3.0 consists of an introduction (which contains the licensing information and a copyright notice) and three chapters.
2. I want to distribute chapter 2 only, so I make a verbatim copy of it.
3. I copy the licensing info and the copyright notice from the introduction.
4. I create a PDF of it.

   Now this PDF only contains content exactly as written by the authors (so I didn’t change any words or added some myself), but it does not contain *everything* the authors wrote in the original work.

Is this allowed?

Comment: No, but you can always ask the author for permission.

Comment: Follow-up: [Does CC BY-ND 4.0 allow distribution of parts?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5402/138)

Answer (score 9):

No. Any modifications you apply that aren't sanctioned by the owner are classed as derivative works. Your result still contains the author's material, true, but you've changed the way it's presented - it's like removing some code that's just a wrapper for a routine. You're changing the product, which creates a derivative work, which is disallowed.

**tl;dr:** No - you must distribute verbatim.

Answer (score 9):

No, that is not allowed. You have transformed the work by **removing** parts. That is not different from transforming it by **adding** or **changing** parts.